# integrate for and if loop using python

Tags: python-3.x

I want to combine for and if loop into a single line:

```
for temp in payment.find({'courseid':cid}):
    is_purchase = True if cid == temp['courseid']  and ids == temp['userid'] else False
```

I did like this:

```
is_purchase = True if cid == temp['courseid']  and ids == temp['userid'] else False for temp in payment.find({'courseid':cid})

# and

is_purchase = for temp in payment.find({'courseid':cid}) True if cid == temp['courseid']  and ids == temp['userid'] else False
```

but it shows an error tell me the right one...

Comment: share the error stacktrace with the code

Comment: Yayati Sule: I get no error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Seems like you forget square brackets for list comprehension. And you can use `any()` for check if any of those values is `True`.

```
is_purchase = any(
    [temp['courseid'] and ids == temp['userid'] for temp in payment.find({'courseid':cid})]
)
```

Comment: True if [temp['courseid'] and ids == temp['userid'] for temp in payment.find({'courseid':cid})] else False